# What are origins and when did the tradition of the Yule Candles come into existence as a Christian tradition?

Tags: tradition, origin, christmas

**What are origins and when did the tradition of the Yule Candles come into existence as a Christian tradition?**

I stumble upon this Christmas Candle idea as a tradition. Can anyone help find more information on it?

When did this become a Christian tradition?

[image: The Yule Log]

[**The Yule Log**](https://archive.org/details/dolphinecclesias01newyuoft/page/56/mode/2up)

Comment: _Like other traditions associated with Yule (such as the Yule boar), the custom may ultimately derive from Germanic paganism._ [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yule_log)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One potential answer: It may have been popularized at Oxford.

> On [Christmas Eve] our ancestors were wont to light up Candles of an uncommon size, called Christmas Candles*[...]
>
> *In the Butter of St John's College, Oxford, an ancient candle-socket of one still remains, ornamented with the figure of the Holy Lamb. It was formerly used to burn the Christmas Candle in, on the high-table, at supper, during the twelve nights of that festival.

--*[Observations on Popular Antiquities](https://books.google.com/books?id=ImhEAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA250-IA1&dq=yule%20candle%20origin&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiYvLa2t-zuAhWOWM0KHYj8CvoQ6AEwBXoECAQQAg#v=onepage&q=yule%20candle%20&f=false): Chiefly Illustrating the Origin of Our Vulgar Customs, Ceremonies, and Superstitions, 1877*

But yes, it could be of pagan origin as well.

> On the eve of the winter solstice, the Anglo-Saxons burnt a large block of wood, as an emblem of returning light and heat, from whence may be traced the custom of burning a *yule-clog* on the eve of Christmas. On the introduction of candles, numerous large candles were lighted, to afford light to the in-door festivity, together with the log. Hence the *Christmas Candle*, and the denomination of the *Feast of Lights* sometimes given to the Christmas festival.

--*[History of the Christmas Festival](https://books.google.com/books?id=vSZhAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA41&dq=%22christmas%20candle%22%20origin&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwik4o74uOzuAhXHKs0KHQBZAwUQ6AEwAXoECAUQAg#v=onepage&q=%22christmas%20candle%22%20origin&f=false), the New Year, and their peculiar customs*, 1843